# Encountering arbitrary limit for setInterval / setTimeout in Node

Tags: node.js, timer, setinterval

I am creating an application that can display radio data on a frontend graph using sample data received from the backend. In order to create decent graph resolution with accurate interpolation, I need to send hundreds of samples per second to the client (with a websocket). Sending sample data is managed by an interval function, which I changed to using a [compensating function](https://gist.github.com/manast/1185904?permalink_comment_id=3709553#gistcomment-3709553) based on drift errors:

```
export class RegulatedInterval {
  // provides more accuracy than typical node interval, which is subject to drift
  baseline?: number;
  timer?: NodeJS.Timeout;
  function: Function;
  duration: number;
  args: any[];
  
  constructor(func: Function, duration: number, ...args: any[]) {
    this.baseline = undefined;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.function = func;
    this.args = args;
  }

  run() {
    if (this.baseline === undefined) {
      this.baseline = new Date().getTime() - this.duration;
    }
    this.function(...this.args);
    
    const end = new Date().getTime();
    this.baseline += this.duration;

    let nextTick = this.duration - (end - this.baseline);
    if (nextTick < 0){
      nextTick = 0;
    }
    this.timer = setTimeout((run: Function) => run(true), nextTick, this.run.bind(this));
  }

  stop() {
    if (this.timer)
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
}
```

However, I noticed that both this class and the native `setInterval` were both limited to a certain rate per second. With a testing script, I found this number to be approximately 70-75 cycles per second. Decreasing the interval moment for either of these would not produce any better performance in my main script or my testing script (which is unburdened by other things that would significantly interfere with event loop performance).

Does Node limit timers and `setInterval` calls somehow? How can this be avoided to create tasks that need to run at a rate faster than 100 cycles per second?